# Another Conway's Game of Life in Haskell

Tags: haskell, game-of-life

Curious what people think about this implementation of Conway's Game of Life in Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

module Test.Conway (
  conwayCalculateAge,
  conwayStep,
  conwayMakeRandom,
  conwayMakeRandomIO,
  conwayMakeEmpty
  ) where

import           Data.Array.Repa
import           Data.Array.Repa.Stencil
import           Data.Array.Repa.Stencil.Dim2
import           Data.Functor.Identity
import           System.Random

conwayNeighborsStencil :: Stencil DIM2 Int
conwayNeighborsStencil =
  [stencil2| 1 1 1
             1 0 1
             1 1 1 |]

conwayStep :: Array U DIM2 Int -> Array U DIM2 Int
conwayStep r =
  runIdentity . computeP . szipWith rules r .            -- Apply rules
  mapStencil2 (BoundConst 0) conwayNeighborsStencil $ r -- Find # neigbors
  where
    rules 1 2 = 1 -- Alive and has two neighbours
    rules _ 3 = 1 -- Alive or dead and has three neighbours
    rules _ _ = 0 -- All others are dead

conwayMakeRandom :: RandomGen g => g -> DIM2 -> Array U DIM2 Int
conwayMakeRandom g sh =
  fromListUnboxed sh $ take (size sh) $ randomRs (0, 1) g
```

Naturally, `conwayMakeRandom` creates the initial grid and `conwayStep` advances the evolution a grid.

Answer (score 2):

That's a nice use of `stencil2` and Repa. All in all there isn't much to review, it follows [a common approach on Conway's Game of Life with Repa](https://www.slideshare.net/kizzx2/repagolpdf). No type signatures are missing, but with Repa it's more or less mandatory to add them.

Well done. But the next time, consider adding *all* your code, `conwayCalculateAge` and `conwayMakeEmpty` were probably interesting (I suspect `conwayMakeRandomIO` to be the same as `conwayMakeRandom` but using `randomRIOs = randomRs (0, 1) <$> newStdGen`).